# Selenium c# clear spinner default value and write new value

Tags: c#, selenium, exception

In a popup of a website there is a spinner that 1 is its default value. I want to clear this value and enter new value.

```
IWebElement enterValue = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.k-widget.k-window > div.k-popup-edit-form.k-window-content.k-content > div > div:nth-child(8) > span.k-widget.k-numerictextbox > span"));
enterValue.Click();
```

If i use `enterValue.Clear()` instead of `enterVakue.Click()` I'll get exception:

> Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

If I put `enterValue.Sendkeys(Keys.Backspace)` after `Click()` , I'll get exception:

> unknown error: cannot focus element.

Same for `enterValue.Clear()`
I tried different solutions from stack overflow but non of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
action.SendKeys(enterValue, "120").Build().Perform();
```

[**Clear date input fails on chromewebdriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360362/clear-date-input-fails-on-chromewebdriver)